# React-redux: actions with variables

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

so i've this action:

```
export const getMovieDettails = (id) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type: GET_MOVIE_DETTAIL_LOADING})
    fetch(`api/movieId/${id}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(movie => dispatch({type: GET_MOVIE_DETTAIL_LOADED, payload: movie}))
        .catch(err => dispatch({type: GET_MOVIE_DETTAIL_FAIL, payload: "Error with API"}));
}
```

on App.js i do this:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onGetShows: () => dispatch(getHomeShows()),
    onGetMovies: () => dispatch(getMoviesShows()),
    onGetSeries: () => dispatch(getSeriesShows()),
    onGetMovieDettail: (id) => dispatch(getMovieDettails(id))
  }
}
```

and then pass the function to

```
<Route path="/movie/:id"  render={(routeProps) => <MovieDettailsRouter key={routeProps.match.params.id} data={this.props.movieDettail} movieDettail={this.props.onGetMovieDettail} {...routeProps}/>}/>
```

so on MovieDettailRouter i do

```
componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props.match.params.id);
        this.props.movieDettail(this.props.match.params.id);
    }
```

but not work, how can pass the function with paramaters, for good experience i call all state and actions on App.js and then pass data on the component, for call without paramaters i don't have problems, everything it's fine, but here where i need to get the params for the actions 've problem, on v1 of App i don't use actions for this page, i use only for page without actions with params, but on this update i decide to use redux for every call on server and i need to understan how can pass an actions with params on components

Edit: Add the state on MovieDettailRoute

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be passing the state to the MovieDetailsRouter component.
After the data is fetched, dispatched and the store changes all the components that are listening for that part of the store will update. 
The component needs to have access to the state to get the data.

You can pass the data to the component by getting the part of the state that your action will update with mapStateToProps in the App component, and then pass it to the MovieDetailRouter

Comment: yeah i forget to pass the state, i add now, but the function don't work

Comment: resolve, now work everything work, there's problem with fetch

Comment: Great! Good luck with your project.